# ZVT Terminal Transaction Declined From ECR

Tags: sockets, terminal, hex, payment

I have managed to create connection and to send data to ZVT Terminal but it appears problem in the end of the transaction, the first step is to send amount to the terminal which I do like this:

`cn.write('\x06\x01\x0f\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x19\x40\x06\x04\x40\x02\xff\x00');`

then after swiping card in terminal it requires to enter the pin of the card which is good but when I press OK button in terminal after entering the PIN CARD then I get this message **Transaction OK** then immediately changes the screen to **Transaction Declined From ECR**.

If someone has experience with ZVT terminal would be good to help me.

Comment: I just had to deal with this topic as well, we have made our project available on Github for this purpose. https://github.com/Portalum/Portalum.Zvt

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly with "PIN CARD"? This cardtype does not exist in the list of ZVT-card-types (in chapter 10 of the ZVT protocol). You can use any card type from this list ..but the provider has to enable this type on a terminal. I.e. some terminals read "fleet cards" and some don't - you cannot enable this by yourself, it has to be done by the provider!